# Upload and Insert multiple images with different input names to database

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, multiple-file-upload

I have 3 input fields for images with different input names (image1,image2,image3) which I did the front end here (https://plnkr.co/edit/RR6XKb5r3CSBfhLrR3Td?p=preview
). Please have a look at this to understand better.

I tried doing the back-end this way with the knowledge I gained so far, on uploading a single image into the database. But now I want to upload 3 images with 3 different input names or inputs to the attributes (image1, image2, image3)in my database that will belong to one unique Id using this way, but when I submit the form, it does not work. Like I said I was just using the knowledge I learned so far with uploading single image.

Can anyone help me achieve my goal?
Regards.
"Code before the form"

```
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $permited  = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
    $file_name = $file['image1']['name'];
    $file_size = $file['image1']['size'];
    $file_temp = $file['image1']['tmp_name'];

    $file_name2 = $file['image2']['name'];
    $file_size2 = $file['image2']['size'];
    $file_temp2 = $file['image2']['tmp_name'];

    $file_name3 = $file['image3']['name'];
    $file_size3 = $file['image3']['size'];
    $file_temp3 = $file['image3']['tmp_name'];

    $div = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($div));
    $unique_image = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10).'.'.$file_ext;
    $uploaded_image = "../uploads/".$unique_image;

    $div2 = explode('.', $file_name2);
    $file_ext2 = strtolower(end($div2));
    $unique_image2 = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10).'.'.$file_ext2;
    $uploaded_image2 = "../uploads/".$unique_image2;

    $div3 = explode('.', $file_name3);
    $file_ext3 = strtolower(end($div3));
    $unique_image3 = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10).'.'.$file_ext3;
    $uploaded_image3 = "../uploads/".$unique_image3

    if($file_name == "" || $file_name2 == "" || $file_name3 == "" || ){
        $msg = "<span class='error'>Fields must not be empty!</span>";
        return $msg;

    } elseif ($file_size >1048567 || $file_size2 >1048567  || $file_size3 >1048567) {
         echo "<span class='error'>Image Size should be less then 1MB!
     </span>";

    } elseif (in_array($file_ext, $permited) === false || in_array($file_ext2, $permited) === false || in_array($file_ext3, $permited) === false ) {
        echo "<span class='error'>You can upload only:-".implode(', ', $permited)."</span>";

    } else{
        move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $uploaded_image);
        move_uploaded_file($file_temp2, $uploaded_image2);
        move_uploaded_file($file_temp3, $uploaded_image3);

        $query = "INSERT INTO product(image, image2, image3) VALUES('$uploaded_image', '$uploaded_image2', '$uploaded_image3')";
                $inserted_row = $this->db->insert($query);

                if($inserted_row){
                        echo "<span class='success'> Your images has been uploaded successfully. </span>";
                    } else{
                        echo "<span class='error'> Sorry! Your images are not added! Try again later. </span>";
                    }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to know what the problem is since you only say that "it is not working" could you be more specific? What errors are you getting? What is not working? Not uploading the files? Not saving the file names to the database?

Comment: By the way, your database design is not sound, you are storing all the images related to a product on one row, that kind of defeats the purpose of using a *relational* database. Images (or image path-name) should be stored as entries in their own table. Then you should decide how they are related to a product. It seems like one image would be related always to *one* and *only one* product, that is a `1 -> *` relationship, in that case you would store the `product_id` as a foreign key on the image table.

Comment: Trust me I tried doing it that way. But I couldn't do it that way unfortunately. Then I opted to do it this way. I've gone through lots of tutorials online but its making me more and more confuse and it is traumatizing me. So as to my problem Whenever I submit my form it doesn't submit don't why. Did you at least check https://plnkr.co/edit/RR6XKb5r3CSBfhLrR3Td?p=preview to see my front end?

Comment: I did, I could not get the form to submit on the preview that you sent but I downloaded the code and, locally, the form submits once the action is a valid url and I removed the `required` attribute on the `<input>` fields, so it seems like there are a few problems. Could you clean your code an post an edit? It would help you find the problem. There are also several problems in your `php` code, missing semicolon on line 35, an extra *or* `||` on line 37.

Comment: What you mean by clean the code?